# How to get the name of the linkyou clicked on using php?

Tags: php

I'm retrieving some info from tables which are already in my database.
Let's say from student table, I'm retrieving the names of all students and print all these names in a way that make them clickable (when you click on any name redirect you to another page)....
My problem is : How can I know on which student name the user clicked? I want to know which student name the user had clicked to retrieve the other info that are related to that student like (Address, sex, cell phone, email ,... ets)

Here is some of the code:

```
enter code here

$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
    $student= $row ['student_name'];
    print ("<a href=info.php'> $student</a>");
    print ("<br>");

  }
```

Comment: I really need your help guys, thanks a lot :)

Comment: You should add an id parameter to your link and on the second page query the db for that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usign with `id`

```
$id      = $row['id'];
$student = $row['student_name'];

print ("<a href=info.php?id=$id'>$student</a>");
```

And you can get student `id` with `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the unique id of the student in your link.

```
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
    $student= $row ['student_name'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    print ("<a href=info.php?id=$id'> $student</a>");
    print ("<br>");

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("<a href=info.php?name='.$student.'> $student</a>");
```

Get the name clickes
    $name=$_GET['name'];